# Why is this pointer (pGame inside WinProc) NULL?

Tags: c++, windows, oop, winapi, pointers

This is my WinMain:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    if(SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        {
            Game game;

            game.CreateRessources(hInst);

            game.ShowMainScreen();

            HWND hwnd=game.Getm_hWnd();
            HWND* pHWND=&hwnd;

            game.pWinsock->Initialize(hwnd);

            ShowWindow(game.Getm_hWnd(),SW_MAXIMIZE);
            UpdateWindow(game.Getm_hWnd());

            MSG msg;
            ZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));

            while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

There is my window creation class:

```
void Game::CreateWindowClass(HINSTANCE hInst)
{
    // Create a window class
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra=NULL;
    wClass.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra=NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon=NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm=NULL;
    wClass.hInstance=hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc=WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName="Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to register window class","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    m_hWnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "Window Class",
            "Game",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_MAXIMIZE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            this);

    if(!m_hWnd)
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,"Window class creation failed","Window Class Failed",MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

This is Game::CreateRessources:

```
void Game::CreateRessources(HINSTANCE hInst)
{   
    CreateWindowClass(hInst);

    pD2DResources=CreateD2DResources(m_hWnd);
    pMessageLog=CreateMessageLog();
    pWinsock=CreateWinsock();
}
```

And finally, my WinProc up to slightly after the lines: if(pGame==NULL)
            MessageBox(NULL,"Pointer pGame is NULL","Error",NULL);

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(msg==WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
            Game* pGame = (Game*)pcs->lpCreateParams;

            ::SetWindowLongPtrW(
                hWnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA,
                PtrToUlong(pGame)
                );
    }

    else if(msg==WM_DESTROY)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        Game* pGame = reinterpret_cast<Game*>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hWnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
                )));

        if(pGame==NULL)
            MessageBox(NULL,"Pointer pGame is NULL","Error",NULL);

        if(pGame->pD2DResources!=NULL)
        {
            switch(msg)
            {
```

For some reason, pGame is NULL since the MessageBox pops up. Why so?

Edit: By the way, I am dynamically creating a few objects and private pointers inside my game object are assigned to these dynamically created objects. Could it have to do with the problem?

Comment: In the braquets below if(msg==WM_CREATE) and else a few more lines below.

Comment: Good to know. What messages are sent before WM_CREATE?

Comment: It would work before I changed many things inside my code. I could have access to an object created outside my WinProc like this.

Comment: `WM_NCCREATE` is sent before `WM_CREATE`, but that isn't the problem as the `this` pointer is sent along with the `WM_CREATE` message. I cannot see all the code, but you should return `TRUE` after calling `SetWindowLongPtrW`.

Comment: What portion of the code could cause the problem?

Comment: You'll find a better C++ application template here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx. It gets all the pointer stuff and window creation messages right.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your WndProc with a debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: How do you do that with visual studio 2010? That will be most useful!

Comment: I found out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `WM_CREATE` is not 1st message the window procedure gets. See `WM_NCCREATE`.

Comment: I've even seen instances of messages like `WM_GETMINMAX` info happening before `WM_NCCREATE`.